# Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future performance

Tags: cocoapods

The following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/git fetch --unshallow
```

...yields the following error:

```
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, I've edited your question to make it a bit more readable. But there is still information missing, please add it: What exactly are you doing, how is the repo set up, etc. - Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I also happened this error

Answer (score 34):

It also happened on my Terminal...

```
YJCMBP:LCBlur yuanjincang$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (4.2.5)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
claide (1.0.0, 0.9.1)
colored (1.2)
escape (0.0.4)
fourflusher (0.3.0)
fuzzy_match (2.0.4)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
minitest (5.8.3, 4.3.2)
molinillo (0.4.5, 0.4.1)
nap (1.0.0)
netrc (0.7.8)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-update (2.5.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
xcodeproj (1.0.0, 0.28.2)
YJCMBP:~ yuanjincang$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Fetching: cocoapods-core-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-core-1.0.0
Fetching: cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.0
Fetching: cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0
Fetching: cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Fetching: cocoapods-search-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-search-1.0.0
Fetching: cocoapods-stats-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-stats-1.0.0
Fetching: cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0
Fetching: cocoapods-try-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-try-1.0.0
Fetching: cocoapods-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-core-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-core-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-search-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-search-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-stats-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-stats-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-try-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-try-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-1.0.0
9 gems installed
YJCMBP:LCBlur yuanjincang$ pod --version
1.0.0
YJCMBP:LCBlur yuanjincang$ pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future performance
```

Wait a while here...

```
[!] /usr/bin/git fetch --unshallow

error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

YJCMBP:~ yuanjincang$
```

---

### APPEND

Maybe I found the **SOLUTION**, just run this line:

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

And then run `pod setup` again.

Done!

Comment: There may be a lot of similar questions, but the answer is not what they want.Nearly ten people have scored, and finally I got -1 too

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. upvoted Leo... gg

Answer (score 16):

Well, I found a solution.
pod update --verbose --no-repo-update

Comment: Usually when we execute update commands, we automatically update the  CocoaPods's spec repository.Adding --no-repo-update arguments can be omitted.

Comment: Thank you so much..I can solve the issue.You are great.